What is going on with these avocados?
I recently cut open an entire bag of avocados to find that all of them were browning inside, in a pattern of veins of brown/black running through the fruit's flesh.  You can especially see this in the cross-section of the avocados in the middle of the picture.
I know that avocados oxidize and turn brown, and that there is nothing harmful about this and you can still eat oxidized avocados just fine. Other people have asked about this and there is a type of oxidization that can happen as a pattern of veins, but I've never seen it this bad: thick, dark, and in particular with empty spaces opening up in the middle of the brown sections. It seems to me like there might be a different or additional phenomenon at play here.
Is it a mold or a fungus, or just the natural extension of the oxidization and browning?
In particular, I'm wondering - is it contagious from avocado to avocado? Maybe I could have saved most of the bag if I had found the bad one(s) early on?


Does this answer your question? have these avocados gone bad?

They have just gotten too old/ripe and have rotted. You said they were in a bag - was it plastic? If so, the humidity in the bag may have sped up the process. This page has some relevant info
